# How can I unfollow my all Facebook friends at once?

Tags: facebook

When I accept any friend request or send any request, I start following them automatically.

How can I unfollow everyone at once?

I tried to unfollow people one by one but it's taking a long time. Please show me a faster way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no option available to unfollow everyone at once. You have to do it [one by one](https://www.facebook.com/help/104941232944896/?ref=u2u).

But you can **Unfollow people to hide their posts** from [News Feed Preference](https://www.facebook.com/help/371675846332829).

To unfollow a person, Page or group from your News Feed preferences:

1. Click **Unfollow people to hide their posts**
2. Select a person, Page or group

Note: When you unfollow someone, you won't see their posts in your News Feed, but you'll still be friends with them.